# How can I use anaconda in zeppelin?

Tags: python, apache-spark, anaconda, apache-zeppelin

I want to use anaconda in zeppelin.

So I modify the configure file in /zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh
like below.

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/jin/spark
export PYTHONPATH=/home/jin/anaconda3/bin/python
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/jin/spark/python
```

Because I think when I modified the PYTHONPATH then I could use the anaconda version.

```
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/interpreter/python.html

Path of the already installed Python binary (could be python2 or python3).
If python is not in your $PATH you can set the absolute directory 
(example :/usr/bin/python)
```

But python version doesn't be changed. I try to check the python version in zeppelin notebook.

```
%python

import sys

print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)


2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
```

How can I use anaconda in zeppelin?

Comment: I don't know anything about zeppelin, but according to these docs, you're pretty close: http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/python.html#conda

Comment: Thank you for answering. When I change the .bashrc to add anaconda path, it works. But I don't want to modify .bashrc so I try using python.conda.

Answer (score 1):

The `python.conda` interpreter was added in 0.7.0.

Here are related PRs

- Conda Interpreter: https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/1645
- Improve Conda Interpreter: https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/1868

So, i would like to suggest to use 0.7.0+ and refer [Zeppelin Doc: Conda Interpreter](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/python.html#conda).

Comment: When I use "%python.conda list" then "java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory" error is occurred.

Comment: I am using 0.7.0 and I don't see any reference to Conda in the interpreter list.  The instructions at http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/python.html#conda will not work.  What should the interpreter settings for conda look like?

Comment: @ChuckCarlson Can u create new python interpreter? Then i think you will see `python.conda`. Because your python interpreter setting had been created before `python.conda` was implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to use Anaconda in Zeppelin:

1. Within the Zeppelin UI click 'Interpreter'
2. Find the section for the 'Python' interpreter
3. (In the Python interpreter section) Set 'zeppelin.python' to '/home/YOUR USERNAME/anaconda2/bin/python'

   print(sys.version)
   2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that you cannot install conda via pip. You need, at a minimum, miniconda. Here's what I did on an Ubuntu 16.04 system:

1. Download the miniconda installer from https://conda.io/miniconda.html
2. Install miniconda
   I chose to install to `/opt/miniconda3`, you can choose differently
3. Update your PATH before starting Zeppelin
   i.e. `PATH=/opt/miniconda3/bin:$PATH`

At this point it should work. You can try it out by creating a new notebook (or opening an existing notebook), typing `%python.conda info` in a paragraph, and running that paragraph.

One downside to this is that you end up using the Python interpreter bundled with miniconda rather than the Python interpreter installed with the system.

Answer (score 0):

do:

- in apace zeppelin ui click on interpreter.
- find python interpreter
- click on edit
- change below property:

  zeppelin.python -------> **path of python in anaconda**

for example:

- *zeppelin.python* : **/home/abbas/anaconda/bin/python**